# keep first row after calculating difference between rows with dplyr::lag

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, lag

My question is similar to this [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933296/calculate-duration-difference-between-first-and-n-rows-that-match-on-column-valu) and this [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57123188/calculate-difference-between-rows-but-keep-the-raw-value-by-group), with a minor difference that seems to be overly complicated.

Example of my data:

```
ind_id   wt   date
1002     25   1987-07-27
1002     15   1988-05-05
2340     30   1987-03-18
2340     52   1989-08-15
```

I am calculating the difference between `wt` values after `group_by(ind_id)`.

To do this:

```
df<-df %>% 
    group_by(ind_id) %>%
    mutate(mass_diff=(wt-lag(wt))
```

This gives me this output:

```
ind_id   wt   date        mass_diff
1002     15   1988-05-05  -10
2340     52   1989-08-15  22
```

But, the output I want should keep the *first* `wt` record, not the last.

Desired output:

```
ind_id   wt   date        mass_diff
1002     25   1988-05-05  -10
2340     30   1989-08-15  22
```

Note that the `wt` column is the only one I'd like to have maintained from the first row. (Keep in mind that this example is overly simplified and I am actually working with 18 rows).

Any suggestions (using `dplyr`) would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(ind_id = c(1002, 1002, 2340, 2340), wt = c(25, 
15, 30, 52), date = structure(c(6416, 6699, 6285, 7166), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")

df %>% 
  group_by(ind_id) %>%
  mutate(mass_diff = (wt-lag(wt))) %>% 
  mutate(wt = first(wt)) %>% 
  slice_tail %>% ungroup

#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   ind_id    wt date       mass_diff
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <date>         <dbl>
#> 1   1002    25 1988-05-05       -10
#> 2   2340    30 1989-08-15        22
```

Comment: Do you suppose there is a way to do the reverse? That is, move the row 1 `wt` record to row 2? (This way I can skip the step for the date (because there are other columns - not shown here) that matter from row 2.

Comment: My just edited solution does that exactly, @BlunderingEcologist.